# Перевод строки в cp1251

Tags: python, python-3.x

Никак не могу понять как в `Python 3` перевести такую вот строку

```
u'Имя представителя'
```

в cp1251.

В Python 2 работала такая конструкция:

```
 u'Имя представителя'.encode('cp1251')
```

Сейчас делаю все так же, но получаю крокозябры. Что делать ?

Comment: приведите два *полных* примера кода (с заголовками), которые демонстрируют разницу, потому что результаты должны быть идентичны как в Питоне 2 так и 3. Следует также явно описать ваше программное окружение (вывод в Windows консоль, в файл или куда-то ещё?)

Comment: Вывод в csv-файл, который будет открыт через exel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED
Чтобы вывести текст в файл в нужной кодировке используйте параметр encoding при открытии файла для записи. Перекодировать текст специально не нужно.

```
with open('d:\\testfile.txt', mode='w', encoding='cp1251') as file:
    text = 'текст'
    file.write(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = u'Имя представителя'
print(a.encode('cp1251').decode('cp1251'))
```